# C# Passing a pointer of array to function starting at specific offset

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, porting

I'm porting a C++ application to C# and experiencing some issues with pointers.

What I'm trying to achieve is to pass an array pointer with an offset so the passed function can work on the correct part of an array. I don't want to change the function's signature to add an extra value for the offset.

So, this is an example piece of C++ code I would like to pass in C#:

```c++
void DoSomething( double p[] )
{
    p[0] = 0.4;
    p[1] = 0.4;
}

int main()
{
    double Vector[3];

    Vector[0] = 0.2;
    Vector[1] = 0.2;
    Vector[2] = 0.2;

    DoSomething( &Vector[1] );
}
```

How could I do that ? Keeping in mind that I can't pass the offset ?

**[Edit]**
Thank you all for the answers.
First, I have to apologize: I made a big mistake while copying the code.

I wrote

```
DoSomething( Vector[1] );
```

on last line instead of

```
DoSomething( &Vector[1] );
```

this has been corrected.

I then realized that I was not very clear about the signature.

- I can slightly change the signature of the function, but I can't add any arguments
- I am already using the "unsafe" and "fixed" keywords, so it won't hurt me
- It doesn't need to be efficient code since this porting is intended to be a Quick & Dirty implementation of an algorithm written by somebody else for a prototype project. If the project is a "Ok go", the code would be thrown at garbage and rewritten in a C++ dll.
- The function "DoSomething" is actually a nest of a few other functions, it is designed as a fast math work but sadly, I don't have all the knowledge about to code it myself. That's why I assume the author has nicely designed its function since it's used world-wide.

I'll try with Servy's suggestion and come back to you in a few days when I'll get back.

Comment: This is pretty poor C++ code as well. I'd use an enumerator myself.

Comment: I agree with IdeaHat and Yakk. It is possible to write `p[3] = 0.4;` in the C++ `DoSomething`. How would you know the array bounds?

Comment: You can use LINQ like this:  var filtered = Vector.GetRange(index,count)....  Change Vector array to List<Double>

Comment: @JohnPeters - important to point out this creates a new array.  The system expects to change elements in the array so this will not functionally work.

Comment: There is no practical way to accomplish this without changing the signature of the called method. Why are you against doing that? What's so wrong with pushing the offset itself to the method that needs it?

Comment: @PeterDuniho - actually the object oriented way of doing this (remember C# is an object oriented language) is to create a new object - a new "Array Type" that provides the functionality.  Servy has a good start below.

Comment: @Hogan: what a weird thing for you to write; OOP doesn't mandate the creation of new types or objects for _all_ problems. But in any case, the point is that the OP has specifically asked not to change the signature of the called method, which pretty much eliminates any of the good solutions (including Servy's). And if the method signature _is_ to change, the most efficient way to address the question is to simply pass the offset to the method and let it deal with the issue.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - I don't believe I mentioned mandating anything --  I simply said that in OOP you use objects to solve problems.  Seems valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *impossible* to do without changing the signature of `DoSomething` at all, but you can avoid needing to pass along both an array and it's offset side by side all over the place.  You can do that by creating a class that composes an array and also keeps track of an offset:

```
public class ArrayReference<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    //you can keep these entirely private if you prefer
    public T[] Array { get; private set; }
    public int Offset { get; private set; }
    public ArrayReference(T[] array, int offset)
    {
        Array = array;
        Offset = offset;
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return Array[index + Offset];
        }
        set
        {
            Array[index + Offset] = value;
        }
    }

    public int Length
    {
        get
        {
            return Array.Length - Offset;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = Offset; i < Array.Length; i++)
            yield return Array[i];
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public static ArrayReference<T> operator +(
        ArrayReference<T> reference, int offset)
    {
        return new ArrayReference<T>(reference.Array, reference.Offset + offset);
    }

    public static ArrayReference<T> operator -(
        ArrayReference<T> reference, int offset)
    {
        return new ArrayReference<T>(reference.Array, reference.Offset - offset);
    }

    public static implicit operator ArrayReference<T>(T[] array)
    {
        return new ArrayReference<T>(array, 0);
    }
    public static implicit operator T[](ArrayReference<T> reference)
    {
        return reference.ToArray();
    }
}
```

You may want to add additional functionality to this, based on your specific needs.  You can expose as much or as little of the underlying array's functionality as you need/want.

Comment: Yes, making a new object type is the C# way to solve this problem.  Personally I think it would be easier to just change the `DoSomething()` function.  But to each his own.

Comment: Note that this changes the signature of the method, just as passing the offset would.

Comment: @Hogan For this very simple example passing along an offset with the array is likely simple enough, sure, but in a program that is dramatically more complex, and that deals with a lot of arrays that have constantly changing offsets, it's actually reasonable to wrap all of the logic for managing the logic of an array with an offset into a class.  Whether the OP's *real* problem is suitably complex to warrant this is a decision he'll need to make for himself.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Indeed.  It's *impossible* not to change the signature in some way and have the described behavior.  There is no way to create an *actual* array of the same type that is merely a reference into another array.  The best you could do without changing the signature is copy the array, and then copy all of the data back after calling `DoSomething`.

Comment: @Servy - I agree, this is why I gave you all my up votes.  I'm mystified why anyone would down vote.

Comment: @Servy: be that as it may, a requirement is a requirement. Even if it makes the question impossible to answer. Your answer is good from a generalized point of view, but efficiency-wise it's inferior to just convincing the OP to accept a signature change to take the offset, due to the need to create a new object just for the purpose of the method call.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The requirements say he doesn't want to pass the offset along with the array into the method.  This doesn't do that.

Comment: @Servy: also -- "The best you could do without changing the signature is copy the array" -- technically not quite true. The closest one could come to satisfying the precise requirements of the OP is to use unsafe code, pin the array, and pass the address of the element at the offset. IMHO that's a terrible way to go, but given the requirements, _that_ is as close as you can get in C#.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The method accepts a `T[]`, not a `T*`, so no, `unsafe` code would still require changing the signature.

Comment: @Servy: I wrote the _closest_. As I already said, it's not possible without _any_ signature change (except by making a copy of the array of course). But passing a T* is closer than changing to a whole different object type and allocating a whole new object for each call to the method.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Actually it *is* changing it to accept a whole different object type, and it *is* creating a new object for each call to the method.  Pointers are their own type, and you'd be creating new instances of them.  I don't know how you're defining "closer" in terms of method signatures, but either he can't change it at all, and any change is too much, or he can, and this is probably his best course of action.

Comment: @Servy: a pointer is a value type. It's not the same as allocating a new object in the heap (but there is other overhead for the `fixed` statement of course...I'm not saying there's no overhead). In any case, I'm sure the OP can at this point decide for themselves what is best to do. They stared with a silly restriction, so naturally they are getting silly responses (including my own).

Comment: @PeterDuniho Allocating a pointer is indeed different than allocating a reference type, but an allocation happens in both cases.  The allocation is *different* with a pointer, not *omitted*.  And once again, the restriction was to not pass along an offset along side the array.  There was no restriction that the signature not be modified at all.  You're inventing the silly restriction when none was made.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually not the way you would do it in C#.

The only way to do this is to use unsafe code, and even then it wouldn't be a good implementation, because your method would be unsafe, and your array must be `fixed`.

The `fixed` keyword would prevent your array to be moved in another place in memory by the garbage collector, but it could lead to partitioned memory and then worse performance.

Moreover, even by design this isn't a good thing, because you don't know your array boundaries in your method.

But if you really want to do this, go with the enumerators.

In your main method:

```
double[] d = new double[3];
d[0] = 1.0;
d[1] = 2.0;
d[2] = 3.0;

IEnumerator<double> e = d.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
e.MoveNext();
tryEnumerate(e);
```

and then your `DoSomething` method:

```
static void DoSomething(IEnumerator<double> e)
{
    while(e.MoveNext())
        Console.WriteLine(e.Current.ToString());
}
```

Comment: First off, you'd really want to be using `IEnumerable` here, not `IEnumerator`, second, that would be a read only view onto the data structure; his intent here is to mutate the data.

Answer (score -3):

Code updated to show chaining using extension methodology.  You can easly return any and all changes and update anything wanted.

```
List<double> Vector;
Vector.Add(0.2);
Vector.Add(0.2);
Vector.Add(0.2);
DoSomething(Vector.GetRange(index,count));
```

If you need to maintain the original list do this:

```
public static List<double> GetRange(static List<double> list, int index, int count){
     return list.GetRange(Index,Count);
}
public static List<double> DoSomething(static List<double> list){
     //do something here
}
```

Use it like this:

```
OriginalList().GetRange(Index,Count).DoSomething();
```

Comment: This won't work DoSomething changes elements of the array -- this will just change the copy.

Comment: That's creating a copy of the list.  Changes to that copy won't affect the original list.